# no such column in SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a table named **User** in `SQLite` which consists of 3 column, **Name, Password** and **Image**.

**MyDatabaseHelper**

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="mm.db";
    public static final String TABLE_USER="User";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="Name";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="Password";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE="Image";
    public static final String ID="id";

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_USER + " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT,Password TEXT,Image BLOB )");
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MyDatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version" + oldVersion + "to" + newVersion + ",which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("Drop TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }
}
```

When I tried to retrieve image from `SQLite` and placed into `ImageView`, I get error, but when I insert data, it works fine.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name;
    private MyDatabaseHelper mdb=null;
    private SQLiteDatabase database= null;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mdb = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
        database = mdb.getWritableDatabase();
        Button createAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.profile);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePicture);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(getRoundedBitmap(picture));
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

        createAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String personName = name.getText().toString();
                String selectQuery = " SELECT " + MyDatabaseHelper.KEY_IMAGE + " FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + MyDatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME + " = " +personName;
                Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    byte[] temp_image = cursor.getBlob(1);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp_image, 0, temp_image.length);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
09-12 17:33:09.083  14231-14231/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: alex (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Image FROM User WHERE Name = alex
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:888)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:499)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
            at com.example.seng.healthyapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4230)
```

> The alex is actually a userName I typed, but it said no such column.

Comment: Uninstall app and run again. It will work :)

Comment: You need to put `alex` in `' '`

Comment: **SQL fundamentals**!! `WHERE Name = 'alex'`. Or better: use **bound parameters**.

Comment: @AnandSavjani No, it won't.

Comment: what if I want to have a where clause ?

Comment: Did you read my comment, which includes a (correct) WHERE clause?

Comment: You mean I can write in this way `WHERE Name = 'personName'` ?

Comment: Of course. That's how SQL works. You really miss the basics.

Comment: @Rotwang would you mind to share with me on how to use **bound parameters** since you said it is better ?

Comment: John, would you mind to use Google, please?

Comment: yeah,everything can be found on Google, so no need to have SO...wohooooo XD

Comment: John, SO is not a Google replacement. And it's a good training for you (for everyone, actually) to search and find tutorials about new things. SO is the last resort when you searched for hours and could land to nothing. Then, and only then, SO is your gold mine. But be sure to search for already answered questions, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your string in single quotes, like

```
SELECT Image FROM User WHERE Name = 'alex'
```

Comment: what if I want to have a where clause ?

Comment: String selectQuery = " SELECT " + MyDatabaseHelper.KEY_IMAGE + " FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + MyDatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME + " =  ' " +personName+" ' ";

Comment: you have to enclose with quotes